# UNUserNotificationCenter did receive response with completion handler is never called iOS11, objective-C

Tags: objective-c, unusernotificationcenter

Occasionally one of my users reports that he does not receive a sound or banner that should be posted when

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler

  is called by the system. I have an internal trace that runs on devices that have received my app from the App Store and confirm that this method is not called.  The trace also shows that multiple (64) notification requests have been posted to the system. I have done extensive searching for this issue and all suggested answers reflect what I am doing in the code.  Here is the code in appDelegate that sets up the notification center and the delegate methods (non-relevant code omitted is indicated by three dots). I would appreciate any help in trying to solve this problem.

  ```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
          // Override point for customization after application launch.
          NSUserDefaults *storage = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
          UNUserNotificationCenter* center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];

          UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
          if (notification) {

              NSLog(@"application didFinishLaunching with UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey");
              [self applicationDidBecomeActive:application];
          }


          UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
          if (notification) {
              // run after a delay so that the cordova/kendo app has time to get ready
              //  [self performSelector:@selector(postNotification:) withObject:notification afterDelay:4.0];
              NSLog(@"application didFinishLaunching with UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey");
              [self applicationDidBecomeActive:application];
          }
  ```

…

```
  center.delegate = self;
    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionAlert + UNAuthorizationOptionSound)
                          completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                              // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
                              NSUserDefaults *storage = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
                              if(granted == YES){
                                  [storage setBool:YES forKey:@"permission granted"];
                                  [storage setBool:YES forKey:@"alert permission granted"];
                                  [storage setBool:YES forKey:@"sound permission granted"];
                              }else{
                                  NSLog(@"No permission granted");
                                  [storage setBool:NO forKey:@"permission granted"];
                              };
                          }];
```

…

```
 #pragma mark UNNotificationCenter setup

    UNNotificationAction *acceptAction = [UNNotificationAction actionWithIdentifier:@"ACCEPT_IDENTIFIER" title:NSLocalizedString(@"Continue notifications", nil) options:UNNotificationActionOptionAuthenticationRequired];
    UNNotificationAction *declineAction = [UNNotificationAction actionWithIdentifier:@"DECLINE_IDENTIFIER" title:NSLocalizedString(@"Stop notifications", nil) options:UNNotificationActionOptionAuthenticationRequired];
    UNNotificationAction *doNotDisturbAction = [UNNotificationAction actionWithIdentifier:@"DO_NOT_DISTURB_IDENTIFIER" title:NSLocalizedString(@"Start Do Not Disturb", nil) options:UNNotificationActionOptionAuthenticationRequired];
    NSArray *actions = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:acceptAction, declineAction, doNotDisturbAction, nil];
    // NSArray *intentIdentifiers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"none", nil];
    UNNotificationCategory *invite = [UNNotificationCategory categoryWithIdentifier:@"com.nelsoncapes.localNotification" actions:actions intentIdentifiers: @[] options:UNNotificationCategoryOptionNone];
    NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObjects:invite, nil];
    [center setNotificationCategories:categories];
    [center requestAuthorizationWithOptions:(UNAuthorizationOptionAlert + UNAuthorizationOptionSound)
                          completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
                              // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
                          }];

    [self setupWatchConnectivity];
    return YES
```

…

```
    #pragma mark UNNotification received in background
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler{
    [center getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler:^(UNNotificationSettings * _Nonnull settings) {
        NSLog(@"notification settings were changed");
        NSUserDefaults *storage = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [storage setBool:YES forKey:KEventLoggerEventNotificationSettingsChanged];
        [storage synchronize];


        if (settings.authorizationStatus != UNAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
            // Notifications not allowed
            NSLog(@"notification settings were changed");
            item.eventDescription = KEventLoggerEventNotificationsNotAllowed;

            // check settings for alert and sound
        }
       // UNNotificationSetting alertSetting = settings.alertSetting;
            if(settings.alertSetting == UNNotificationSettingEnabled){
                [storage setBool:YES forKey:@"alert permission granted"];
                item.eventDescription = KEventLoggerEventAlertsAreAllowed;
            }else{[storage setBool:NO forKey:@"alert permission granted"];
                item.eventDescription = KEventLoggerEventAlertsAreNotAllowed;
            }
            if (settings.soundSetting == UNNotificationSettingEnabled){
                [storage setBool:YES forKey:@"sound permission granted"];
                item.eventDescription = KEventLoggerEventSoundsAreAllowed;
            }else {[storage setBool:NO forKey:@"sound permission granted"];
                item.eventDescription = KEventLoggerEventSoundsAreNotAllowed;
            }

    }];
    NSLog(@"appdelegate - center didReceiveNotificationResponse");
    NSString *actionIdentifier = response.actionIdentifier;

    UNNotification *notification = response.notification;
    if([actionIdentifier isEqual:@"com.apple.UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier"] || [actionIdentifier isEqual:@"com.apple.UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier"]){
    }else{


        BOOL accept = [actionIdentifier isEqual:@"ACCEPT_IDENTIFIER"];
        BOOL stop = [actionIdentifier isEqual:@"DECLINE_IDENTIFIER"];
        BOOL doNotDisturb = [actionIdentifier isEqual:@"DO_NOT_DISTURB_IDENTIFIER"];

        if (accept){NSLog(@"accept");
            [self handleAcceptActionWithNotification:notification];
        }
        else if (stop){NSLog(@"stop");
            [self handleDeclineActionWithNotification:notification];
        }
        else if(doNotDisturb) {NSLog(@"do not disturb");
            [self handleDoNotDisturbActionWithNotification:notification];
        };
    }

    completionHandler();
}
```

…

```
*#pragma mark UNNotification received in foreground
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler{
    NSLog(@"appdelegate willPresentNotification");
    [center getNotificationSettingsWithCompletionHandler:^(UNNotificationSettings * _Nonnull settings) {
        NSLog(@"notification settings were changed");
        NRCEventItem *item = [[NRCEventStore sharedStore]createItem];
        item.eventDateTime = [NSDate date];
        item.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
        item.eventSender = [self description];

        NSUserDefaults *storage = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];


        if (settings.authorizationStatus != UNAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
            // Notifications not allowed
            NSLog(@"notification settings were changed");
            item.eventDescription = KEventLoggerEventNotificationsNotAllowed;
            // check settings for alert and sound
        }
        if(settings.alertSetting == UNNotificationSettingEnabled){
            [storage setBool:YES forKey:@"alert permission granted"];
            item.eventDescription = KEventLoggerEventAlertsAreAllowed;
        }else{[storage setBool:NO forKey:@"alert permission granted"];
            item.eventDescription = KEventLoggerEventAlertsAreNotAllowed;
        }
        if (settings.soundSetting == UNNotificationSettingEnabled){
            [storage setBool:YES forKey:@"sound permission granted"];
            item.eventDescription = KEventLoggerEventSoundsAreAllowed;
        }else {[storage setBool:NO forKey:@"sound permission granted"];
            item.eventDescription = KEventLoggerEventSoundsAreNotAllowed;
        }

    }];
    UNNotificationRequest * request = notification.request;
    NSString * actionIdentifier = request.identifier;
    if([actionIdentifier isEqualToString:UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier] || [actionIdentifier isEqualToString:UNNotificationDefaultActionIdentifier]){
    }else{
            NSLog(@"app delegate notification received while in foreground");



            // remind the user
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"notification", nil) message:@"Timer expired!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
            NSLog(@"app delegate willPresentNotificationWithCompletionHandler: dnd is not started");
        }else{
            NSLog(@"app delegate willPresentNotificationWithCompletionHandler: dnd has started");
            [center removeAllPendingNotificationRequests];
            [center removeAllDeliveredNotifications];
        }
    }



    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert + UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound);

}*
```

Comment: Please update your question with a notification payload.

Comment: These are local notifications not push